# How to put Context through Bundle

Tags: java, android

I have to put Context object in bundle and send it in the input value.

```
in.putParcelable(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_URI, sourceDocumentUri);
in.putParcelable(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_TARGET_URI, targetParentDocumentUri);
in.putInt(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_FILE_COPY_OPERATION, operation);

in.putSerializable(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_CONTEXT, (Serializable) context);
```

I tried like this, but got exception, how can I put?

Comment: Why do you need to put the context in your bundle? If you need the context from a fragment, use `getActivity()`

Comment: But I have to use Context in utils java file, not in any activities or fragments. Then how can I have to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever pass context. Otherwise it's a. a source of memory leaks and b. a source of crashes. Since you are creating a Bundle, I assume you are going to start up another app component, and (as already pointed out by Will) every app component (and fragments) has access to its own Context, so there's really no need to do that.

Comment: But I have to use Context in utils java file, not in any activities or fragments. Then how can I have to manage that?

Comment: Usually a Utils file contains static methods. It's safe to pass a `Context` into a static method.

Comment: Based on the code sample in your question, you are trying to put Context into a bundle. Why do you want to do it?